# Pythonのリストについて

Tags: python, python3

python3についての質問です。
list()と[]は同じものだと思っていたのですが、

```py
a = [map(int,input().split())]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])

b=list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in range(len(b)):
    print(b[i])
```

を実行すると

```
>>>
123
<map object at 0x036D88D0>
123
123
>>>
```

という異なる結果になりました。
原理的なことを教えてもらえると助かります。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]`はその中に要素を並べてリストを作ることができます。したがって、前者は単一の`map object`からなるリストになります。

一方`list`は`list()`とすれば空のリストを、`list(iterable)`のようにすれば`iterable`(今回の場合`map object`)と同じ要素を持つリストを返します。

リスト自体も`iterable`ですので、次の結果を見ると理解しやすいかもしれません。

```
In [4]: a = [[1,2,3]]

In [5]: b = list([1,2,3])

In [6]: a
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3]] # [1,2,3]を要素に持つリスト

In [7]: b
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3]
```